# Opencart Vqmod Error Writing Log

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I want to ask opencart problem, I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

OK

{"country_id":"100","name":"Indonesia","iso_code_2":"ID","iso_code_3":"IDN" ,"address_format":"","postcode_required":"1","zone":[{"zone_id":"1507","country_id":"100","name":"Aceh","code":"Aceh","status":" 1"},{"zone_id":"1508","country_id":"100","name":"Bali","code":"Bali","statu s":"1"},{"zone_id":"1509","country_id":"100","name":"Banten","code":"Banten ","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1510","country_id":"100","name":"Bengkulu","cod e":"BE","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1511","country_id":"100","name":"D.I.Yogy akarta","code":"YG","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1512","country_id":"100","nam e":"Gorontalo","code":"GO","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1513","country_id":"10 0","name":"Jakarta","code":"Jakarta","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1514","count ry_id":"100","name":"Jambi","code":"JA","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1515","co untry_id":"100","name":"Jawa Barat","code":"JB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1516","country_id":"100","name ":"Jawa Tengah","code":"JT","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1517","country_id":"100","nam e":"Jawa Timur","code":"JI","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1518","country_id":"100","name ":"Kalimantan Barat","code":"KB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1519","country_id":"100","name ":"Kalimantan Selatan","code":"KS","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1520","country_id":"100","na me":"Kalimantan Tengah","code":"KT","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1521","country_id":"100","nam e":"Kalimantan Timur","code":"KI","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1522","country_id":"100","name ":"Kepulauan Bangka Belitung","code":"BB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1537","country_id":"100","n ame":"Kepulauan Riau","code":"KPR","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1523","country_id":"100","name ":"Lampung","code":"LA","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1524","country_id":"100", "name":"Maluku","code":"MA","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1525","country_id":"1 00","name":"Maluku Utara","code":"MU","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1526","country_id":"100","name ":"Nusa Tenggara Barat","code":"NB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1527","country_id":"100","name ":"Nusa Tenggara Timur","code":"NT","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1528","country_id":"100","name ":"Papua","code":"PA","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3970","country_id":"100","n ame":"Papua Barat","code":"PB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1529","country_id":"100","name ":"Riau","code":"RI","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3971","country_id":"100","na me":"Sulawesi Barat","code":"SR","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1530","country_id":"100","name ":"Sulawesi Selatan","code":"SN","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1531","country_id":"100","na me":"Sulawesi Tengah","code":"ST","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1532","country_id":"100","nam e":"Sulawesi Tenggara","code":"SG","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1533","country_id":"100","n ame":"Sulawesi Utara","code":"SA","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1534","country_id":"100","name ":"Sumatera Barat","code":"SB","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1535","country_id":"100","name ":"Sumatera Selatan","code":"SS","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"1536","country_id":"100","na me":"Sumatera Utara","code":"SU","status":"1"}],"status":"1"}<b>Warning</b>:

file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\rumahjoy\vqmod/logs/Fri.log) [<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/sloki/user/h1604/sites/rumahjoy.com/www/vqmod/vqmod.php</b> on line <b>395</b>LOG FILE COULD NOT BE WRITTEN
```

I have 2 question:

First, what happen with my vqmod? It got C:\xampp (localhost). I've hosted it to server which must be /home/sloki/user/.......

Second, what's wrong with JSON error? Because at localhost it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to VQmod 2.3.2 then its solved..